# How to determine which client was used in IdentityServer4

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

I implemented most of IdentityServer4 and .NET Core 2 following the Quickstarts and it works well.
However I wish to separate the access from the application and to the API running on the same web. I have an application and an API running on the same web and I want to give a secure access to this API while the application also needs a login.

So on the web site, I want users to be able to access the application as well as the API.
However for external applications which should only access the API, I wish they cannot access the rest of the application.

I understand I could do this by having 2 different webs: one for the application and one for the API but I wish to have them both on the same URL.

So I think I simply need 2 different clients connected to the same users database (using ASP.NET Identity):

```
 new Client
 {
     ClientId = "sapi",
     ClientName = "Secure API",
     AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,

     RequireConsent = true,

     ClientSecrets =
     {
         new Secret("secret".Sha256())
     },
     RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" },
     PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc" },

     AllowedScopes = { "sapi" }
 },

 // OpenID Connect hybrid flow and client credentials client (MVC)
 new Client
 {
     ClientId = "mvc",
     ClientName = "MVC Client",
     AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,

     RequireConsent = false,

     ClientSecrets =
     {
         new Secret("secret".Sha256())
     },

     RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" },
     PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc" },

     AllowedScopes =
     {
         IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
         IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
         "sapi"
     },
     AllowOfflineAccess = true
 }
```

So the idea is that the client *mvc* can access the application and API, while *sapi* client can only access the API and not the application. Any user (stored in ASP.NET Identity) can be used with client *mvc* or *sapi*.

The problem is how do I tell if the user has been authenticated using client *mvc* or using client *sapi*?

Answer (score 0):

When the user has logged in, in the claims you will have one claim named `aud`. It's value should be the clientId. Then you can have some custom authorization to either reject or allow authorization to the application.